# WPF control directly inside Excel CTP

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, ctp

Currently I have a WinForm user control in the Excel CTP, which in turn
hosts a WPF user control via an element host. Things are working well
except for performance issues.

My question is - is it possible to load the WPF control directly
without using a winform wrapper? i.e. expose the WPF user control or window as an active x control that I can pass directly to ICTPFactory::CreateCTP ?

Please note - I am not using VSTO. I am using Microsoft.Office.Core directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - this question has been out there for quite a while. So - I'm going to take a stab at answering it.

Preferred Solution - DONT DO IT! WPF and Excel CTP just don't seem to mix. There are tons of issues right from UI refresh issues to focus and air space issues.

Alternate Solution - Create an unmanaged activex control and use it as the CTP. Then use the HWND of the unmanaged activex control and the [HwndSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.aspx) class to parent WPF user controls on the unmanaged activex controls.

Edit: I am going to leave this question open - in case someone can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Hi, do you have any guidance / code skeleton regarding your propose Alternate Solution? I never though of using an unmanage CTP to host our WPF user controls but it might be worth digging.